# Send data FROM Servlet to Html

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet which generates json data and i want to send this json data to an html page and display it there.

Now i **dont** want to append the json data in the url and then read it in the html, because the json data can be huge and url has a size limit.

**My requirement needs html and not jsp's.**

I am not able to get any working solutions in javascript.

Still searching for the same in js,jquery or ajax.

Please do let me know alternatives i can try out,examples of the same is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: do u want to use ajax?

Comment: yea if there's a solution using the same i would love to try it out

Comment: ok..first of all do u know how ajax works?

Comment: its like u will b on a html page and click on something,it will go to the server and pass the JSON  back..do u want it like this??

Comment: json back to the same html page?
how do you do that

Comment: thats the magic of ajax...if u click on something do u want the json to appear?

Comment: yes 
so when i click on say a href it hits the servlet and then returns and displays the returned json onto the same html?

Comment: yes u can do that....i will post d code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html page write this JQuery
Include jquery.js necessary files

```
<script>
$('a').click(function (event){ 
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $.post('../servlet_name',
            {
               param1:value1 //here incase you want to pass something to servlet
            },
            function(msg) {
                //msg is what u will get from the servlet
            });
});
</script>
```

In your servlet pass the JSON using

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(jsondata);
```